# Simple TCP/IP Chat using sockets on android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a beginner in android programming and i want to ask for your help in android studio.. I need to make an application that is client-server based chat with in a local area network.. how can i build this app and what could be the easiest way to do it..

Comment: Looks like your best bet is to search for tutorials.  You aren't asking a specific question that anyone can answer.

Comment: you can start work from opensource project.[firechat](https://firechat.firebaseapp.com/)

Comment: create a chat server then create a wrapped app base on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to tell you how to code this because that is for you to figure out, but I will tell you what you need to do.

First of all you will need to create the server. You would do this using Java by opening a TCP socket on say port 946 or any other socket that isn't already bound to/being user. Then you will need to make a packet handler that will handle the message packets that are sent by the client.

Now for the client side you will need to create a socket for the client and connect that socket to the remote host. Now you will create your message packets and send them over this newly created socket to the remote host and the server will handle the packets as you coded it to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code to get you started.

**On the Server side**

I believe you know how to create the android UI using the xml layout.
In the xml layout, add a button, a listView, with ids.
The button onclicked will start the server, and keep it open to receive messages from the client.

On the MainActivity, after Creating an instance of the two, Button, and ListView, finding there Ids with the findViewById. 
Set the listView to an adapter that you created.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this,   R.layout.list_items, list);
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

and on button clicked call the method below.

```
public void startListening(){
    myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6000);
                while(st) {
                    Socket socket = server.accept();
                    Message clientMessage = Message.obtain();
                    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    String strMessage = (String) ois.readObject();
                    clientMessage.obj = strMessage;
                    myHandler.sendMessage(clientMessage);
                    ois.close();
                }
                server.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.obj = e.getMessage();
                myHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    myThread.start();
}
```

to start the server and keep it open using the while loop for data to be received from the client.
Now add this method to update the UI thread.

```
 Handler myHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message status){
        String myMessage = status.obj.toString();
        list.add(myMessage);
    }
};
```

**On the Client side**

In the xml add an EditText and a send button to send data to the server.

In the mainActivity, after creating instances of the editText and Button, and find their ids with the findViewById.

```
    editText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
```

Onclick of the send button do this.

```
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myString = editText.getText().toString();
            sendData();
        }
    });
```

Bellow is the sendData() method.

```
public void sendData(){
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6000);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject(myString);
                oos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

**Run the two projects on the same android device or emulator.** 
I think this should get you started.